Pydantic でバリデーション動作の変更をするには？
現象
以下のようなコードで実装していました。
class PostNameRequest(BaseModel):
  key:int = None
  name:str

@router.post("/{name_key}")
def post_api_name_update(
  name_key:int,
  req_item:PostNameRequest
):
 ...
 return

keyが指定していなくても許容して、nullとしてDBに書き込まれていました。
しかし、バージョンが大幅に更新されおり、keyが指定してない場合、エラーが発生するようになりました。
確認したこと
依存関係があったFaseAPI,Pydantic,rstcheckのアンインストールと、2023年7月以前バージョンへの再インストールを行いました。
しかし、元の動作にはなりませんでした。
知りたいこと
int型でもnullを許容する書き方。以下の記述が正しいのでしょうか？
key:Optional[int]=None


回答が付かないのは、「なにをしたらどこでどんなエラーになったのか」と「『以下の記述が正しいのでしょうか？』と聞いているのは試してみて駄目だったからなのか」が質問を読んでも分からないからかな、と思いました。そのあたりの情報が追加されるとよさそうです（エスパー回答だと「正しいでしよう」しか書けなくて、解説しようがない）

参考
このサイトに移行ポイントがまとめられていました。
FastAPIがPydantic v2対応したので、V2移行のポイントを紹介する(意外と簡単)
重要な点
今回、動作に影響があった点を参考にしたサイトをもとに列挙します。
1. 既定値が None の場合は、=None の指定が必須になった
明確にNoneの指定が必要となったことで、全ての対象箇所で変更が発生します。
Optional指定のクラス、変数も、以下のように明示する必要があります。
key:Optional[int]=None
option:Optional[ClassOption]=None

2. dict()が非推奨化、model_dump()に置き換え
変更前
data.dict()

変更後
data.model_dump()

dict()の置換を行うと、通常のdict()も変換されてしまうので、.dict()を置換するように注意が必要。
3. class Config ではなく model_config = ConfigDict()
BaseModelの参考となるスキーマを定義するときに、以下のように変更となります。
変更前
    class Config:
        schema_extra = {
            "example": {
                "mode": "Normal",
            }
        }

変更後

    model_config = {
        "json_schema_extra" : {
            "example": {
                "mode": "Normal",
                "startup": "PointSwitch or MemorySwich",
            }
        }
    }

記述を変更しなくても、動作しますが、VScodeでは警告が頻発します。
